# Cumulative sum that resets when 0 is encountered

Tags: r

I would like to do a cumulative sum on a field but reset the aggregated value whenever a 0 is encountered.

Here is an example of what I want :

```
data.frame(campaign = letters[1:4] , 
       date=c("jan","feb","march","april"),
       b = c(1,0,1,1) ,
       whatiwant = c(1,0,1,2)
       )

 campaign  date b whatiwant
1        a   jan 1         1
2        b   feb 0         0
3        c march 1         1
4        d april 1         2
```

Comment: The answers to [this question I asked a couple of weeks ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247414/create-sequential-counter-that-restarts-on-a-condition-within-panel-data-groups) should help you solve this problem.

Comment: Related: [Create counter within consecutive runs of certain values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012516/create-counter-within-consecutive-runs-of-certain-values)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Another base would be just

```
with(df, ave(b, cumsum(b == 0), FUN = cumsum))
## [1] 1 0 1 2
```

This will just divide column `b` to groups according to `0` appearances and compute the cumulative sum of `b` per these groups

---

Another solution using the latest `data.table` version (v 1.9.6+)

```
library(data.table) ## v 1.9.6+
setDT(df)[, whatiwant := cumsum(b), by = rleid(b == 0L)]
#    campaign  date b whatiwant
# 1:        a   jan 1         1
# 2:        b   feb 0         0
# 3:        c march 1         1
# 4:        d april 1         2
```

---

Some benchmarks per comments

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(0:1e3, 1e7, replace = TRUE)
system.time(res1 <- ave(x, cumsum(x == 0), FUN = cumsum))
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.54    0.24    1.81 
system.time(res2 <- Reduce(function(x, y) if (y == 0) 0 else x+y, x, accumulate=TRUE))
# user  system elapsed 
# 33.94    0.39   34.85 
library(data.table)
system.time(res3 <- data.table(x)[, whatiwant := cumsum(x), by = rleid(x == 0L)])
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.20    0.00    0.21 

identical(res1, as.integer(res2))
## [1] TRUE
identical(res1, res3$whatiwant)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: This, annoyingly, needs to calculate `cumsum` twice. :-/

Comment: Can you try with `with(rle(df1$b!=0), sequence(lengths)*rep(values, lengths))`

Comment: @akrun I'm getting different results. Maybe you right and we are wrong, dunno.

Comment: I coded it based on the assumption that the column values were 0, 1.  Your example is different so it wouldn't work.

Comment: @akrun oh, so maybe undelete your answer and put that as an assumption. Your solution should be very efficient in that case I'd guess.

Comment: @DavidArenburg It's okay.  I think your solutions are general.

Comment: Thanks it is perfect, I also like tried your your one akrun and works pretty well too.

Comment: @patpat akruns solution works only if your column is binary,

Comment: @akrun your  `rle` solution will work if you do `rle(data ==0)`  or something to that effect, making it essentially binary.  (And since `rle` is my favorite Rswissarmycodeknife,  I hope you'll edit and undelete your answer :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thanks for the comments.  I did try with some general data such as `v2 <- c(3, 2, 0, 1,1,2,0,4)` . But, after a few attempts, I couldn't find a concise way enough to beat (:-)) DavidArenburg's elegant code.  If you come up with some, please do post it.

Answer (score 13):

Another late idea:

```
ff = function(x)
{
    cs = cumsum(x)
    cs - cummax((x == 0) * cs)
}
ff(c(0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 5, 2))
#[1] 0 1 4 0 0 5 7
```

And to compare:

```
library(data.table)
ffdt = function(x) 
    data.table(x)[, whatiwant := cumsum(x), by = rleid(x == 0L)]$whatiwant

x = as.numeric(x) ##because 'cumsum' causes integer overflow
identical(ff(x), ffdt(x))
#[1] TRUE
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(ff(x), ffdt(x), times = 25)
#Unit: milliseconds
#    expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#   ff(x) 315.8010 362.1089 372.1273 386.3892 405.5218    25
# ffdt(x) 374.6315 407.2754 417.6675 447.8305 534.8153    25
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `Reduce` function with a custom function that returns 0 when the new value encountered is 0 and otherwise adds the new value to the accumulated value:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) if (y == 0) 0 else x+y, c(1, 0, 1, 1), accumulate=TRUE)
# [1] 1 0 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`hutilscpp::cumsum_reset` is designed for this purpose. The first argument is a logical vector, indicating when the cumulative sum should continue. The second argument is the input to the cumulative sum itself

```r
library(hutilscpp)
b <- c(1, 0, 1, 1)
cumsum_reset(as.logical(b), b)
```

On my machine, compared to the `data.table` function above, this use of `cumsum_reset` is about 3 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant using `rep` of the values at places where to reset. This uses `cumsum` only once but the drawback will lead to large numbers and can cause an integer overflow or inaccurate numeric values and will propagate `NA` to all following groups.

```
x <- cumsum(DF$b)
i <- which(DF$b == 0)
x - rep(c(0, x[i]), diff(c(1L, i, length(x)+1L)))
#[1] 1 0 1 2
```

Another way is to use `Rcpp` - in this case for *integer*.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('IntegerVector csrA(const IntegerVector x, int z=0) {
  IntegerVector out(no_init(x.size()));
  int init = z == NA_INTEGER ? 0 : z;
  int s = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
    if(x[i] == z) s = init;
    else [[likely]] s += x[i];
    out[i] = s;
  }
  return out;
}')
csrA(DF$b)
#[1] 1 0 1 2
```

A variant also taking care of NA might look like:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('IntegerVector csr(const IntegerVector x, int z=0) {
  IntegerVector out(no_init(x.size()));
  int init = z == NA_INTEGER ? 0 : z;
  LogicalVector isNA = is_na(x);
  int s = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
    if(x[i] == z) s = init;
    else [[likely]] if(isNA[i] || s == NA_INTEGER) s = NA_INTEGER;
      else [[likely]] s += x[i];
    out[i] = s;
  }
  return out;
}')

csr(c(2,4,3,0,3,5), 0)
#[1] 2 6 9 0 3 8

csr(c(2,NA,3,0,3,5), 0)
#[1]  2 NA NA  0  3  8

csr(c(2,4,3,1,3,5), 1)
#[1] 2 6 9 1 4 9

csr(c(2,4,3,NA,3,5), NA)
#[1] 2 6 9 0 3 8
```

Data

```
DF <- data.frame(campaign = letters[1:4] , 
                 date=c("jan","feb","march","april"),
                 b = c(1,0,1,1) ,
                 whatiwant = c(1,0,1,2)
                 )
```

---

Benchmark - Based on @David Arenburg

```
set.seed(123)
#Using 1e3 instead of 1e2 would lead to an integer overflow for whichRep and cummax
x <- sample(0:1e2, 1e7, TRUE)

library(data.table)

bench::mark(
ave = ave(x, cumsum(x == 0), FUN = cumsum),
data.table = data.table(x)[, whatiwant := cumsum(x), by = rleid(x == 0L)]$whatiwant,
cummax = {cs = cumsum(x)
  cs - cummax((x == 0) * cs)},
whichRep = {y <- cumsum(x)
i <- which(x == 0)
y - rep(c(0, y[i]), diff(c(1L, i, length(x)+1L)))},
RcppNA = csr(x),
RcppSimple = csrA(x)
)
```

Result

```
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_…¹
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:tm>
1 ave           1.06s    1.06s     0.945   751.8MB     3.78     1     4    1.06s
2 data.table 199.01ms 266.26ms     3.76    231.9MB     1.88     2     1 532.53ms
3 cummax      90.57ms  93.76ms    10.4     152.6MB     6.92     6     4  578.4ms
4 whichRep     74.5ms  77.05ms    12.9     195.6MB    11.1      7     6 541.63ms
5 RcppNA      39.55ms  40.84ms    24.2      76.3MB     5.60    13     3  536.1ms
6 RcppSimple  29.73ms  30.59ms    32.3      38.1MB     3.80    17     2  526.1ms
```