# Adding values sequentially since a zero in R

Tags: r, sum, sequence

Hi I'm trying to add up values in a vector since a zero value in R.
I have a vector like this:

```
wdnew
 [1] 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

And I want to create a new vector that counts the number of iterations or places since a zero value. If I did this properly I'd get a vector like this:

```
wdseq
 [1] 1 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

This ought to be straightforward but I can't figure out how to generate the sequence, any suggestions?
Thanks,

Comment: It doesn't matter for this time, but next time please remember to use `dput` to share your example data.

Comment: You have people answering who are assuming there are only zeros and 1s in the vector. Please be more specific. Are there always only zeros and 1s? Or can the nonzero values be any number?

Comment: Lots of answers, @Rose. Can you please "accept" your preferred answer (and potentially upvote any and all you find particularly good)?

Comment: See [this identical post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501902/cumulative-sum-that-resets-when-0-is-encountered)

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use `rleid` to create a group variable and do `cumsum` by group:

```
wdnew <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
ave(wdnew, data.table::rleid(wdnew != 0), FUN=cumsum)
# [1] 1 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: I think the `!= 0` is not necessary..

Comment: @Arun It's not very clear if the original vector contains only 1 and 0. This is to handle that kind of case as pointed out by another user.

Answer (score 4):

An option without `data.table`:

```
wdnew <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
rl <- rle(wdnew)
unlist(mapply(function(a,b) b * seq_len(a), rl$lengths, rl$values))
#  [1] 1 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

As @DirtySockSniffer suggested, this can be combined into a single line:

```
with(rle(wdnew), unlist(mapply(function(a,b) b * seq_len(a), lengths, values)))
```

Or stepping off of @user20650's suggestion:

```
wdnew * sequence(rle(wdnew)$lengths)
```

I think this last one may win the codegolf ...

(All assuming that `wdnew` is all 0s and 1s.)

Comment: not yet, though there are many advocates and many good reasons to use it, it just hasn't reached my "learn-priority" yet

Comment: I would recommend the simplest answer that doesn't rely on external packages as the solution. Looks like this one. This one or the one by @ZheyuanLi

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a loop 'cause you like using loops, you can do this:

```
nums = c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)

runningCount = 0
for(i in 1:length(nums)){
   if(nums[i] == 1){ 
      runningCount = runningCount + 1
      nums[i] = runningCount
   } else {
      runningCount = 0
   }
}

nums
 [1] 1 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to add up values in a vector since a zero

Maybe

```
k <- rle(as.logical(x))$lengths
ave(x, rep.int(1:length(k), k), FUN = cumsum)
```

Note, I am taking a more general setting, where your `x` is not just 0 /1 binary. But `as.logical(x)` will give a `TRUE / FALSE` binary result, indicating chunks of zeros (`FALSE`) and non-zeros (`TRUE`). If your `x` is surely 0 / 1 binary, just using

```
k <- rle(x)$lengths
ave(x, rep.int(1:length(k), k), FUN = cumsum)
```

is legitimate.

---

**Example**

```
set.seed(0); x <- sample(0:3, 20, TRUE)
# [1] 3 1 1 2 3 0 3 3 2 2 0 0 0 2 1 3 1 2 3 1

k <- rle(as.logical(x))$lengths    ## chunk size
# [1] 5 1 4 3 7

ave(x, rep.int(1:length(k), k), FUN = cumsum)    ## cumulative sum each chunk
# [1]  3  4  5  7 10  0  3  6  8 10  0  0  0  2  3  6  7  9 12 13
```

Answer (score 3):

I may win the award for longest answer on this one.

Well, at least I didn't call any packages and stuck to basic functions (FWIW).

```
vec <-  c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1); res  <- vec

for(i in 2:length(vec)){m <- 1
  while(vec[i-m] > 0 & vec[i]>0){m <- m+1}
      res[i] <- m; if(vec[i]==0) res[i] <- 0}
```

> [1] 1 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 3 4 5

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach with `diff` and `ave`

```
ave(wdnew, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(wdnew == 1)!=0)), FUN = seq) * wdnew
#[1] 1 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

#### data

```
wdnew <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```