# How can I count how many rows since a value has changed in a column vector in R?

Tags: r

I am coding analytics on a financial signal that has output of -1, 0, or 1 and am trying to track how many days it has been since the signal has changed for a daily analytics report.

example: if the tail of my df is 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...

end result goal is a vector like: 0 0 0 1 2 3

How might I go about this? My first thought was a for loop of some kind but I only know how to write those in Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cumulative sum that resets when 0 is encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501902/cumulative-sum-that-resets-when-0-is-encountered). Of course, you would want when `x != 0`. Best of luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply use `rle` and `sequence`:

```
vec <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)

with(rle(vec), sequence(lengths) - 1)
[1] 0 0 0 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
sequence(table(rleid(vec)))-1
#[1] 0 0 0 1 2 3
```

Or use `tabulate` as @Andrew suggested (which would be more faster)

```
sequence(tabulate(rleid(vec)))-1
```

#### data

```
vec <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: You could use `tabulate()` as well (in-place of `table()`)

Answer (score 0):

something like this could work. It depends on the structure of your data, you might need to switch `length` with `nrow` for instance

```
data <- c(0,1,0,0,0,0)

c( rep(0,which(data == 1)+1), 1:(length(data)-which(data == 1))-1 )
```

output:

```
> data 
[1] 0 1 0 0 0 0

>output
[1] 0 0 0 0 1 2 3
```

Comment: not quite, the output should be 0 0 0 1 2 3. I flagged another answer that works perfectly above.

Comment: Fixed the answer, but agree the other answer is cleaner.

Comment: This will not work. Recal the signal can be 1, -1 or even 0. You have not taken -1 into consideration. Also you code simply cannot work eg `data <- c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1)` cannot run for your data

Comment: @Onyambu The example given does not properly encapsulate the whole problem.  But I appreciate your thoroughness.  I was trying to think of a way to answer this problem with `diff` Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You cannot use diff here. Recall the data has 1,0,and -1. Check the solution I provided above. The example has `...` which literally means its not the end of the vector