# row id by group resetting after zero/null values

Tags: r

I'm trying to group some messy time series data together based on a value column - essentially I'm trying to create a function that will produce the column `targetid` - that is, the dataset is grouped by `id`, and a new id is created whenever a non-zero value begins again.

```
a <-  data.frame(
  id=rep(1:2,each=8,times=1),
  valuecolumn = c(5,5,10,0,0,0,5,0,5,5,0,5,10,0,0,0),
  targetid = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
)
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247414/create-sequential-counter-that-restarts-on-a-condition-within-panel-data-groups) was probably closest I could find (doesn't work as id resets every non-zero value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I would post an answer to my rather specific question:

```
library(dplyr)
a2 <- a %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(next.valuecolumn = lag(valuecolumn),
         next.valuecolumn2 = coalesce(next.valuecolumn, valuecolumn),
         diff = ifelse(valuecolumn > 0 & next.valuecolumn2 == 0, 1, 0),
         target2 = cumsum(diff)+1)
```

The row id doesn't 'reset', but this is not required for the problem as I can group by user_id-target to sum value by id.